# customizar validator.js ao sair do campo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-3

Boa tarde galera

Estou trabalhando com validator.js (biblioteca bootstrap) para validar campos de um formulário, tenho um campo email customizado:

```
$('#userForm').validator({
    custom: {
        validemail: function($el) {
            if(!valida_email($el.val())) {
                return "Email inválido"
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente, porem preciso fazer uma outra validação e caso a mesma retorne verdadeiro fazer a marcação no fomulário, mas isso somente quando o campo perder o foco, e estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade perante a essa situação.

Uma das tentativas que fiz mas sem sucesso foi a seguinte:

```
 $("#emailUser").blur(function() {
    $("#userForm").validator({
        custom: {
            validemail: function ($el) {
                if (getExistUserCpf($el.val())) {
                    return "CPF já cadastrado";
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Aqui esta o html

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
    <label>Endereço de E-mail</label>
    <input name="emailUser" id="emailUser" type="text" class="form-control email" placeholder="email@address.com" data-validemail required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Espero ter ficado claro minha dúvida.

Comment: Não entendi Everton, os campos já **validam ou não** no evento `blur` pq quer implementar outro **blur**?

Comment: O que implementei no blur não funciona, eu quero que quando o usuário saia do campo email, o mesmo valide se o email digitado já existe no banco de dados, caso existe o campo de email deve ser marcado com a mensagem 'Email já existe' e não deixe salvar o formulário, tudo isso com o validator.js